# How can I list the policies associated with my Azure resources?

Tags: java, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-policy

For each of the resources in my Azure account, I would like to list some basic info about it and then find the policies associated with it.  Using Azure's Java SDK, here's what I have so far:

```
AzureResourceManager azureResourceManager = AzureResourceManager
        .authenticate(credential, profile)
        .withSubscription("<my-subscription-id>");

for(GenericResource resource : azureResourceManager.genericResources().list())
{
    System.out.println("Resource Name: " + resource.name());
    System.out.println("Resource ID: " + resource.id()); 
    PagedIterable<PolicyAssignment> policiesAssignmentsForThisResource = azureResourceManager.policyAssignments().listByResource(resource.id());
    for(PolicyAssignment policyAssignment : policiesAssignmentsForThisResource)
    {
        System.out.println("Policy Assignment Display Name: " + policyAssignment.displayName());
    }
}
```

This will list the resource name and ID, but when trying to loop over the policy assignments, it throws this error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Parameter parentResourcePath is required and cannot be null.
```

Is there a way to resolve this error?  Is there a better way to find the policies for a resource?

Here's the `listByResource()` method that I'm using:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.resourcemanager.resources.models.policyassignments.listbyresource?view=azure-java-stable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the status of thoses policies associated with one resource, please refer to the following code.

NOTE: This is version 1 API, not the current version 2 API, and this code is still in Beta.

Sdk

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.policyinsights.v2019_10_01</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-mgmt-policyinsights</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-beta-2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code

```
        ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(clientId,
                tenant,
                clientSecret,
                AzureEnvironment.AZURE);


       RestClient restClient=  new RestClient.Builder()
                .withBaseUrl(credentials.environment(), AzureEnvironment.Endpoint.RESOURCE_MANAGER)
                .withCredentials(credentials)
               .withSerializerAdapter( new AzureJacksonAdapter())
                .withResponseBuilderFactory(new AzureResponseBuilder.Factory())
                .build();

        PolicyInsightsClientImpl policyInsightsClient = new PolicyInsightsClientImpl(restClient);
        PagedList<PolicyStateInner> policys = policyInsightsClient.policyStates().listQueryResultsForResource(
                PolicyStatesResource.DEFAULT,
                "/subscriptions/e5b0fcfa-e859-43f3-8d84-5e5fe29f4c68/resourceGroups/andywin7"
        );
        for(PolicyStateInner policy : policys){
              System.out.println(policy.complianceState());

        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I agree this code should work, but when I test it I find that it returns every policy assignment for every resource, whether it applies or not.  The console and the Azure CLI exhibit the correct behavior, but the Java SDK does not.

Comment: @james.garriss Could you please describe your issue in detail?

Comment: I did.  For every resource found in my account via `genericResources().list()`, the `listForResource()` method returns every enabled policy, whether they are assigned to that resource our not.  I can see the correct assignments in the portal.  I can retrieve the correct assignments via the CLI using `az policy state list --resource $id`.  But the Java is broken for me.  I don't know why.

Comment: @james.garriss The comamnd `az policy state list` is not used to list assignments, you should use `az policy assignment list` to  list assignments

Comment: No, that CLI command is doing exactly what I want.  Perhaps I should be asking this question:  What Java method is the equivalent to `az policy state list`, @Jim Xu?

Comment: Here's the REST API equivalent:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/policy-insights/policystates/listqueryresultsforresource

Comment: The code in the first half doesn't work.  If you'll drop it and just keep the 2nd half, I'll accept it as the answer.  It does, however, need to be caveated that this is part of the older version 1 API (not the current version 2 API) and that it's beta code.  Thanks for your help, @JimXu.

Answer (score 0):

As I didn't want to use the v1 API, which is still in beta, and the v2 API doesn't have this functionality yet, I chose to use the REST API instead.  I used [OkHttpClient](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/) to handle the heavy lifting. Here's my solution, where I get the policy states for a resource using the resource ID:

```
OkHttpClient policyStateHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
String policyStateUrl = "https://management.azure.com" 
        + resource.getString("id") // This is the resource ID that I have...
        + "/providers/Microsoft.PolicyInsights/policyStates/latest/queryResults?api-version=2019-10-01";

// It's empty b/c it's a POST without a body.  Yes, it's dumb.
RequestBody policyStateRequestBody = RequestBody.create("", null); 
Request policyStateRequest = new Request.Builder()
        .url(policyStateUrl)
        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
        .post(policyStateRequestBody)
        .build();

String policyStateJson = "";
try
{
    Response policyStateResponse = policyStateHttpClient.newCall(policyStateRequest).execute();
    policyStateJson = policyStateResponse.body().string();
    if (!policyStateResponse.isSuccessful())
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Unable to get the policy states for this resource (" + resource.getString("name") + ").");
        System.out.println(" Reason for error: ");
        System.out.println("  " + policyStateJson);
        return;
    }
}
catch (SocketTimeoutException ste)
{
    System.out.println("ERROR: Unable to get the policy states for this resource (" + resource.getString("name") + ").");
    System.out.println(" The reason is that it timed out.  Azure does this a lot.  If you re-run the app, it will likely fix itself.");
    return;
}
catch (IOException ioe)
{
    ioe.printStackTrace();   // TODO Handle this...
}
JSONObject policyStateRootObject = new JSONObject(policyStateJson);
JSONArray policyStates = policyStateRootObject.getJSONArray("value");
for (int j = 0; j < policyStates.length(); j++) 
{
    JSONObject policyState = policyStates.getJSONObject(j);
    // Do something with the JSON
    System.out.println(policyState.getString("policyDefinitionName"));
    System.out.println(policyState.getString("policyDefinitionId"));
    System.out.println(policyState.getString("complianceState"));
}
```